# Dynamic last visible detection

Tags: jquery

I am styling a site where the design requires the main window not to have scrollbars.

So, in order to see the last couple of links of the vertical navigation, I am writing some jQuery code which will animate the navigation upwards revealing any hidden menu links until the user can see them all.

What I need to accomplish is to dynamically detect the current last visible link each time the navigation animates up or down. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

[Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/) might help you.

Be very careful with that behavior because it sounds like it will confuse the user.

Comment: +1 on the behavior warning. and I wish I could chuck you another +1 for the Waypoints link. Sounds like something I can use. :D